# How to assign values from a list of dictionaries to a 2-dimensional parameter in Pyomo

Tags: python, pyomo

I know how to assign values from a single dictionary to a 1-dimensional parameter in Pyomo. For that I use the following code

```
import pyomo.environ as pyo
import pandas as pd



#Define the model
model = pyo.ConcreteModel()

#Read the dataframe from file for one building
df_buildingData = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/Data/H9_HH" + str(1) + "_Day_" + str(4) +".csv", sep =";")

#Define the sets
model.set_timeslots = pyo.RangeSet(1, 288)


#Create the dictionaries for the set
dictionaryHeatDemand_In_W= df_buildingData.set_index('Timeslot')['Q_htg'].to_dict()

#Assign the values from a single dictionary to a 1-dimensional parameter

model.param_heatDemand_In_W = pyo.Param(model.set_timeslots, initialize=dictionaryHeatDemand_In_W)
model.param_heatDemand_In_W.pprint()
```

and I get the following output
[image: Output_1_dimensional_Parameter]

So far so good. However, now I would like to have a 2-dimensional parameter that is based on the set "model.set_timeslots" and the parameter "model.set_buildings". To do that I used the same code but I changed it such that I always work with lists (one entry for every building). Here is the code for the 2-dimensional parameter:

```
import pyomo.environ as pyo
import pandas as pd



#Define the model
model = pyo.ConcreteModel()

#Reading of the data
list_df_buildingData_mHP_EV= [pd.read_csv("C:/Users/Data/H9_HH" + str(index) + "_Day_" + str(4) +".csv", sep =";") for index in range (1,  4)]

#Define the sets
model.set_timeslots = pyo.RangeSet(1, 288)
model.set_buildings = pyo.RangeSet(1, 3)


#Create the dictionaries for the set
list_dictionaryHeatDemand_In_W_mHP_EV= [list_df_buildingData_mHP_EV[index].set_index('Timeslot')['Q_htg'].to_dict() for index in range (0,  3)] 

#Define the parameters of the model in pyomo
model.param_heatDemand_In_W = pyo.Param(model.set_timeslots,model.set_buildings, initialize=list_dictionaryHeatDemand_In_W_mHP_EV)
model.param_heatDemand_In_W.pprint()
```

However, the outcome when using `model.param_heatDemand_In_W.pprint()` does not like the one I would like to have. Here you see a screenshot[image: Output_Multiple_Dictionaries]. There is always a key values at the beginning starting from (1,1) to (288,3). For each of those key values there are 288 entries (288 is the number of set_timeslots). I would like to have a 2-dimensional parameter param_heatDemand_In_W (building, timeslot). So the parameter should have for each of the 3 buildings, 288 timeslots and for each of those timeslots there should be 1 value for the heatDemand.

Any idea how I can do that? I'd appreciate every comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put your data in a dataframe after reading it from a csv file
then define your model as abstract
then you can do two things
1- initializing your parameter as shown in the figure
or

```
def init_w(model,i,j):
    return df.iloc[i-1,j-1]
model.W =Param(model.i, model.j, mutable=True, initialize=init_w)
```

[image]

2- filling the instance properly

Comment: Thanks for your answer Optimization Team. You wrote: "You can put your data in a dataframe". The question is how can I do that. I have a list of dataframes as you can see in the second screenshot. Each of those dataframes has the column "Q_htg" (as you can see in the first screnshot). Now the question is how to create a new dataframe that has as index "Timeslots" and the columns should be the Q_htg value for every builiding.

Comment: I tried 2 approaches in order to achieve what you suggested but both of them failed:
`series = [pd.Series(list_df_buildingData_mHP_EV[index][:, 1]) for index in range (0, len(list_df_buildingData_mHP_EV))]
newDataframe = pd.concat(series, axis=1)`
--> "TypeError: '(slice(None, None, None), 1)' is an invalid key".
And the second approach is `for index in range (0, len(list_df_buildingData_mHP_EV)):
    newDataFrame[index] = list_df_buildingData_mHP_EV[index] ["Q_htg"]`
--> "NameError: name 'newDataFrame' is not defined"

Comment: It is clearly shown in my answer that you can put your data in a csv and read it with pandas then follow the rest

Comment: Thanks Optimization team for yoru answer. Basically I now managed to create this new dataframe with all the values from the different building and I used your approach and it seems to work. I have 2 questions about this: 1) Why do you need to use i-1, j-1 and not i,j (so why do you have to substract one 2) Why do you have to use the iloc function `return df.iloc[i-1,j-1]` and not just `return df [i-1} [j-1]`?

Comment: i starts from 1 in pyomo but data frame starts from 0 
if df [i-1] [j-1] returns the row i-1 and column j-1 then go for it :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer and effort Optimization team. I really appreciate it. I upvoted and accepted your answer.